# Javascript file selection dialog box eventListener not being called

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

The following code is intended to show a button which, if pressed, will open a file selection dialog, allow the user to select one or more files, and then print the selected file names and size to the console.
However, when the button is pressed, the file dialog does open, but nothing appears on the console.  It seems as though the "change" event listener function is not called when the user closes the dialog box.  On the other hand, if I evaluate `fileElem.click();` in the console, in place of pressing the button, everything works as intended.  What's wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>File(s) size</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <p><input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple style="display: none">
    <button id="fileSelect">Select some files</button></p>
</form>

<script>
const fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
const fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem");

fileElem.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    var files = fileElem.files;
    if (files.length) {
        console.log("Filename: " + files[0].name);
        console.log("Type: " + files[0].type);
        console.log("Size: " + files[0].size + " bytes")
        }
    }, false);

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    fileElem.click();
    }, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Behaviour is the same in both Safari and Chrome (current versions).

Comment: Submit buttons submit Add `type="button"` and watch the magic.

Comment: Brilliant!  That does indeed make it work. Thx.